# Is the POSITA skill level a typically a user, maintainer or design engineer?

Tags: posita

If the patent invention is a Television: when considering the obviousness of the part, is the  POSITA skill level a typically a user, maintainer or engineer?

For this discussion we will define:

- user: not having the knowledge of a maintainer or engineer and trained only to operate the TV.   Primary role is to operate: does not have the skill or training to design or maintain.  May identify design defects or innovation opportunities
- maintainer: trained only to install parts and repair.  Does not have the training \ experience of an engineer.   Primary role is maintain or repair, not design, but may identify design defects or innovation opportunities
- engineer: trained in physics, chemistry and mathematics from an ABET college and engaged. Primary role is design and innovate improvements to TVs.

I am trying to get a sense of the skill-level & experience a POSITA will have n the mind of a USPTO examiner.

Comment: This is probably answerable at least in general terms, since there are plenty of judgments with rulings on this. But to the underlying question, I have a suspicion you are overstating the level of thought than an examiner puts into it. If an examiner feels something is obvious, they will make the rejection, regardless of who the POSITA is. They don't typically have the inclination to consider precisely the level of qualifications and experience.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has more to do with the specifics of the invention. Say the invention is a novel bit of TV electronics. Then I would think a person with ordinary skill in the art would be an electrical engineer probably with at least a BS or MS. If the invention is related to the design of the box the TV is delivered in than a packaging engineer. If the invention is related to the user interface then perhaps an industrial designer. In any case, I believe the POSITA should exhibit skill in the specific technological area of the invention itself with additional awareness of the field the invention is applied to.